# non-jquery document ready - is window.onload the best/only way?

Tags: javascript, pageload, document-ready

I want a function to run when the `document` is *ready*, but there's no logical reason to leverage jquery as the little amount of work going on the page doesn't warrant me loading a file of that size.

Typically I would use `window.onload = function(){};` -- as far as I can tell, this is the recommended approach.

Thoughts/recommendations? I would very much like to hear some developer opinions on this if there's a better way.

**Note-**

If this question is better asked elsewhere (because it's somewhat subjective) - please let me know and I'll close it and ask there.

Comment: The "ready" event is called "DOMContentLoaded"...

Comment: If it is working fine, where is the problem? You can use different variations, but it's basically same thing. For example: `<body onload="load()">`

Comment: @mrnull I've learned that there's usually several ways to do things and sometimes one of the ways I don't know is the "better" way. In leu of that statement, I suppose ignorance is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `window.onload` is that it will wait for all content (like images) to be loaded. Typically you only need for the DOM to be ready to be manipulated. You should know though that jQuery eliminates a lot of the cross browser inconsistencies in doing that, and as such doing it yourself will be a small pain in the ass. For that reason, you might want to look into [this library](https://github.com/ded/domready) which contains the bare bones of cross-browser DOM readiness.

Comment: A browser sniffing extract from jQuery as seen in 2008 is better, you think?

Comment: @Xeon06 you make a good point. I looked around for a "DOM ready" equivalent for JS, but it looks like it's a chunk of code if you want cross-browser support. Perhaps my hands are tied..

Comment: @katspaugh I do. The code looks fine, and it's the most recent library I could find on the subject. My answer also warns the OP of the dangers of not using jQuery itself. If you can find a better library I'd be happy to link to it.

@Jackson A chunk of code isn't that bad if it's well encapsulated and isolated. Or you could always use `window.onload` and if this causes problems for you revise the solution.

Comment: 2008 is sure recent. Old Safari and Opera issues are not relevant now. MSIE9 supports `DOMContentLoaded`. If you really can't find anything better – https://github.com/ded/domready

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have an universal supported method for a non-JQuery "domready" event, an option is to create a function which should be executed when the DOM is ready, and add a `<script>` tag at the end of the document:

```
...
<script>
function runOnceReady(){
...
}
</script>
</head><body>
....
<script>runOnceDomReady()</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the equivalent of jQuery.ready event. jQuery is just javascript, so there is no reason you couldn't make a similar event. It is just there to reduce you're work at making your code browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `onload` to your `body` tag on the page.

Do something like:

```
<body onload="myCrazyFunction()">
```